# SMS conversation as threads in android

Tags: android, sms

I am developing an application in which i am only receiving text from numbers. It is just a receiving text sms app and it doesnot allow the user to send message through it. Now if any message comes then it is saved in listview. if another message comes from the same number it is saved as a new list view item. I want to merge this as a thread so that if different messages are coming from same number then it is saved in thread just like normal messaging apps. Remember i am only receiving text and not sending. What to do to apply thread technique to already develop application that save messages as different listview items?
I am not posting code because i dont know what to post because i am just asking for a suggestion and a helping link so that i can apply thread technique.

Answer (score -1):

It is simple, just add a click listener to each number that initiates another layout. look at the example below:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm